# Why does video has a smaller size than photo for an iOS live-photo

Tags: swift, phlivephoto

I am working on an iOS project with live-photos.

Live-photo is a combination of a real photo and a small video of 3 seconds.
The goal of this feature is to let the user choose which is the best picture in the video.

I have made some tests and i see that the photo is 15,356,907 bytes whereas the video is 2,088,228 bytes. I cannot explain why the video is smaller than the photo itself.

Do you think apple is recording video with poor quality ? So how will the user choose the best frame in the video if the quality is poor ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have more to help us? I agree, it makes no **logical** sense that Apple is at fault here. But without any code on your end? We need more details... what makes you make this claim on sizes (code is much preferable), what have you tried (code is preferable), and what have you seen as behavior (details are preferable). Please, for us to help you, you need to give much more detail. EDIT: you probably need to clean up your title also, it's very misleading.

Comment: Are both the photo and the video taken with an iPhone? It's hard to imagine that iPhone can take a 15MB photo.

Comment: Yes it is taken from an iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the video is smaller than the size of the photo. For example, I took a live photo on my phone and the size of it was 3024 pixels by 4032 pixels. The video, on the other hand, was just 1440 pixels by 1080 pixels.